# mysql, how to find last id of inserted row before the given ID for a specific query

Tags: mysql

assume we have to collect data from 2 rows of a table

for example :

```
select * from table where userid=24
```

and it returns for example 3 rows of data with different id of row ( auto increment ) , 3 ,35 ,68

I want to know what's the id of the row before the row with id 35 ( which is 3 ) of about 68 it is 35.

how can I find it by mysql queries?

thank you

Comment: Could you rephrase the question, please?  John's answer below is what I was going to suggest - but evidently from your comment this is not what you're wanting.

Comment: It seems what they're asking would be best accomplished with whatever language you're working with the MySQL results in...
Ideally, you'd return the results in an array (which would be in the same order as the DB), set the pointer to the array with the ID you want, and then just reverse the array pointer by one...

Comment: dear jordan , I did what you suggested before my question . but i was interested to do it with mysql queries ... however I got my answer now.thank you all

Comment: @Will A : thank you for your attention , i found the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-insert-id.html) 
Here is a reference to what you need

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/getting-unique-id.html

EDITED

Perhaps you would like to use a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE rowID < (SELECT rowId FROM table WHERE userid=24)
ORDER BY rowId DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: dear John , that's not what I need , mysql_insert_id() returns the inserted row id , i need something else... i can do it by some other tricks, but i wonder if it's possible to do it by a single query...
I have an id which it's row's userid column is for example 888! i want to ask mysql " what is the last row id befor the given id which the userid is 888 "

however thanks for your reply

Comment: @Cyb3r ... Have a look at the query I posted.  It might help